# How to do arithmetic operations in cmake string

Tags: cmake

What I want to do is create a custom command in cmake. But i want to do some operations in a string paramater of the command.

I have 2 variables set like below.

```
set(VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(VERSION_MINOR 0)
```

I want to multiply VERSION_MAJOR by 10 and add VERSION_MINOR to it. But how can i manage to use user_version like `user_version=VERSION_MAJOR * 10 + VERSION_MINOR`.
This command works fine.

```
add_custom_command(
...
COMMAND sqlite3 ${DB_FILE} "PRAGMA user_version=${VERSION_MAJOR}"
...
)
```

But i want to use it like this.

```
add_custom_command(
...
    COMMAND sqlite3 ${DB_FILE} "PRAGMA user_version=${VERSION_MAJOR * 10 + VERSION_MINOR}"
...
)
```

cmake version: 3.5.1

Comment: Theres a math function in CMake, that is used as follows: `math(EXPR MY_USER_VERSION "${VERSION_MAJOR}*10 + ${VERSION_MINOR}")`

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with the CMake command [`math`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/math.html):

```cmake
set(VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(VERSION_MINOR 0)

# multiply VERSION_MAJOR by 10 and add VERSION_MINOR
# set MY_VERSION to the resulting value
math(EXPR MY_VERSION "${VERSION_MAJOR} * 10 + ${VERSION_MINOR}")

add_custom_command(
    ...
    COMMAND sqlite3 ${DB_FILE} "PRAGMA user_version=${MY_VERSION}"
    ...
)
```